# Cannot see test after adding to Jenkins

Tags: python, jenkins, automated-tests, allure

When creating a job and adding it to Jenkins. Jenkins marks the job as done, but there is no test activity displayed (the test has 24 test cases) and the report from Allure is empty. Do you know what the reason could be? I'm just learning Jenkins.

My repository
https://github.com/localuseremptybottle/Test

Pictures from Settings and log's

[Job Settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tOFju.png)
[Consoleoutput](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MllMu.png)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the console output screenshot of the job, it looks like the report file is written to to the Jenkins workspace inside `allure-report`. It seems like the `--alluredir=reports` isn't being read/used and its writing just to the current directory ( Just a suspicion based on the output, I know nothing about Allure so I'm not sure about the options that takes in/how it works.)

I suspect the report on Jenkins is empty because it didn't find the file at the right path, so it made an empty report.

I believe all you need to do to get the Jenkins report to get the generated report would be to update the **Path** to be `allure-report` inside the Allure Reports section of the job configuration.

Answer (score 0):

I uploaded a light update to the repo to restore the original version. The test passes fine, but nothing is added in Allure. My question is.
Why don't these tests run at all? There are 24 test cases in my repository. You can check the file (Login_test) and if the Allure Jenkins Plugins received the report, then my test on the repository should be supported by the test in the Allure code.(I don't have Allure tags added in my test code)

Allure is not as important to me as that I understand how to add Tests to jenkins so that it works. At the moment, my code, which is quite advanced, does not open.

In the attachment there is a log from the last operation
[Jenkins Log][1]  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/nPbFe.png

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).